# Is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags

Is this Stack Overflow question off-topic? "[What does the X in JAX-RS Stand For?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227456/what-does-the-x-in-jax-rs-stand-for)"

The quote in the off-topic text box says

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

I think John3136, Scary Wombat, John Conde, iCodez, and Edwin Dalorzo are mistaken. JAX-RS is not general computing software. It's a Java API. I've read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic page. It seems like it would fit under "software tools commonly used by programmers". I've also done what is suggested there and looked for similar questions and there are plenty of questions from people asking about initialisms/acronyms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll put it this way.  It's not a question I'd personally *close*, but it's a question I'd *downvote*.  Get enough of these and it disappears from the front page.

The real reason here is that the question amounts to nothing more than trivia, and while there may be a canonical answer, I as a Java professional don't want to pontificate about the meaning of acronyms in my libraries.

It shouldn't have been closed for that reason.  I'm loathe to say it shouldn't have been closed *period*, but it's definitely not one of those sorts of questions that belongs anywhere on the main page.

Downvoting it and letting the roomba get it later seems to be more ideal...

Comment: I still don't get it. You wouldn't close it yet since I posted this question the other question was removed by a moderator.

Comment: Apparently pressing enter submits the comment...
Here is additional stuff I wanted to type:
I think a question asking what the X means in JAX-RS is right up there with asking what "foo" or "MVW" means. Should those questions be closed too?
I think if there are some questions that are simply beneath the consideration of the users here then there should be something added to the on-topic page both so that people know what kinds of questions to ask and so that people can close questions with a relevant reason.
Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: First, it wasn't a moderator that removed it - it was three community members who have [the ability to delete questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) since it was closed for so long.  Second, I merely stated my thoughts on the matter; others had decided to disagree and take their own action (but I don't necessarily disagree - it should be gone).  Third, there's a distinct difference between the definition of a design pattern and the acronym of a tool; I'd lean more towards the former being at least salvageable.